# How to solve example with many modules?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve example with many modules like this:  $| x^3  + x + 1| +  |x^3 - x - 1| = 2x + 1$?

Comment: Keep squaring until all the modulus symbols have gone is one method. This can create solutions for the new problem which are not the solutions of the original problem, so each must be checked,

Comment: I wouldn't say that two is many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example looks like $|a + b| + |a - b|$, where $a = x^3$ and $b = x + 1$.

So if $a > b$ then $2x^3 = 2x + 1$. The only solution (approximately 1.19) does not agree with this.

If $a \le b$ then $2x + 2 = 2x + 1$. So no real solutions.

Therefore you do not have solutions here.

Comment: That was very quick and neat. Definitely a +1

Comment: You can also justify with $x^3>x+1\implies 2x^3>2x+1$.

Comment: How did you solve  $2x^3$ = 2x + 1?

Comment: @MaksimSuprunenko you can solve it with approximation. You can draw the graph and see the point approximately.